# Aggregate framework can't use indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I run this command:

db.ads_view.aggregate({$group: {_id : "$campaign", "action" : {$sum: 1} }});

ads_view : 500 000 documents.

this queries take 1.8s . this is its profile : https://gist.github.com/afecec63a994f8f7fd8a

indexed : db.ads_view.ensureIndex({campaign: 1});

But mongodb don't use index. Anyone know if can aggregate framework use indexes, how to index this query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$group` operator is not one of the ones that will use an index currently.  The list of operators that do (as of 2.2) are:

```
$match
$sort
$limit
$skip
```

From here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes

Based on the number of yields going on in the gist, I would assume you either have a very active instance or that a lot of this data is not in memory when you are doing the group (it will yield on page fault usually too), hence the 1.8s

Note that even if `$group` could use an index, and your index covered everything being grouped, it would still involve a full scan of the index to do the group, and would likely not be terrible fast anyway.

Comment: no, group will not use an index.  I'm not sure you saw the note I added - there would not necessarily be an advantage to using an index here - you would just be switching a table scan for a full index scan.

Answer (score 15):

This is a late answer, but since `$group` in Mongo as of version 4.0 still won't make use of indexes, it may be helpful for others.

To speed up your aggregation significantly, performe a `$sort` before `$group`.

So your query would become:

```
db.ads_view.aggregate({$sort:{"campaign":1}},{$group: {_id : "$campaign", "action" : {$sum: 1} }});
```

This assumes an index on `campaign`, which should have been created according to your question. In Mongo 4.0, create the index with `db.ads_view.createIndex({campaign:1})`.

I tested this on a collection containing 5.5+ Mio. documents. Without `$sort`, the aggregation would not have finished even after several hours; with `$sort` preceeding `$group`, aggregation is taking a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`$group` doesn't use an index because it doesn't have to. When you `$group` your items you're essentially indexing all documents passing through the `$group` stage of the pipeline using your `$group`'s `_id`. If you used an index that matched the `$group`'s `_id`, you'd still have to pass through all the docs in the index so it's the same amount of work.