# Mongodb Aggregation Framework: Does $group use index?

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use aggregation framework with `$match` and `$group` stages. Does `$group` stage use index data? I'm using latest available mongodb version - `2.5.4`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb indexing for aggregates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170636/mongodb-indexing-for-aggregates)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`$group` does not use index data.

From the mongoDB [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes):

> The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.
>
> The $geoNear pipeline operator takes advantage of a geospatial index.
>   When using $geoNear, the $geoNear pipeline operation must appear as
>   the first stage in an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Your first sentence contradicts the rest of your answer: So long as $group is the second stage of a pipeline, and the first is a $sort on the same field(s) as the $group, the index *will* get used.

Comment: @ArthurTacca: $sort stage will use the index, but the $group stage will not.

Comment: I think you're being a bit pedantic: If the $sort stage makes use of the index, and the $group stage uses the result of the sort to avoid an expensive scan, then I would say that $group has used the index. Your quote from the docs does not say either way whether $group take advantage of a prior $sort, so I think you haven't really answered the intention of the original question. (The quote previously in your answer from 3.2 docs strongly suggested that the answer is "yes", hence my original comment; the new quote from 3.4 docs is less suggestive but still ambiguous.)

Comment: @ArthurTacca [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841857/mongodb-aggregation-seems-very-slow) is an example of it not being pedantic.

Comment: @olejorgenb You misunderstand my pendantry. I was saying is that if (**IF**!) (1) `$sort` can take advantage of an index, and (2) `$group` has a special optimised implementation when the previous step was a `$sort` on the same thing, then you could "trick" `$group` into using an index (indirectly) by putting the relevant `$sort` just before it in the pipeline. This answer says an authortative "`$group` does not use index data" but the reference does not rule out what I just said. So I wasn't saying the answer was wrong as such, just that the quoted text doesn't prove it.

Comment: As you can see from the answer I posted below, in fact point (1) is true (`$sort` at the start does use an index, that's even said in the quote in this answer), and (2) is only partly true: `$group` immediately after `$sort` is faster than `$group` without `$sort`, but not as fast as it could be. So overall I would say "`$group` can take advantage of index, but not if it's first, it has to be second, after the relevant `$sort`". This is all irrelevant for the question you linked to, which never really needed a `$group` in the first place; using `$sort` by itself was already enough.

Comment: @ArthurTacca It's worth pointing out that `$group` can be made faster in a few cased by indirectly using the index through sort. I don't really care if we call that "use the index" or not. The problem is that the cases seems to be few and limited. Linked question: In that particular case it was possible to achieve the same using distinct and sort. If you need to do the same for tuples it's not though - unless you count creating more indices, run multiple distinct against these indices and use multiple find+sort on the cartesian product of those distinct results as "not needing `$group`"?

Answer (score 6):

@ArthurTacca, as of Mongo 4.0 `$sort` preceding `$group` will speed up things significantly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56427875/92049.

Comment: Thanks for following up with an answer. That's very interesting. The bug I referenced in my answer is still open (and a MongoDB employee referenced it on Jun 28 2019 so I think it is not an oversight that it's open). So maybe it's (very!) helpful to `$sort` before a `$group` if the `$sort` can use an index, but it could be made even more efficient still. Byt the speedup you observed could be explained by `$group` doing a sort internally, and many sort algorithms are trivial on an already-sorted list.

Answer (score 5):

As 4J41's answer says, `$group` does not (directly) use an index, although `$sort` does if it is the first stage in the pipeline. However, it seems possible that `$group` could, in principle, have an optimised implementation if it immediately follows a `$sort`, in which case you could make it effectively make use of an index by putting a `$sort` before hand.

There does not seem to be a straight answer either way in the docs about whether `$group` has this optimisation (although I bet there would be if it did, so this suggests it doesn't). The answer is in [MongoDB bug 4507](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4507): currently `$group` does NOT have this implementation, so the top line of 4J41's answer is right after all. If you really need efficiency, depending on the application it may be quickest to use a regular query and do the grouping in your client code.

Edit: As sebastian's answer says, it seems that in practice using `$sort` (that can take advantage of an index) before a `$group` can make a very large speed improvement. The bug above is still open so it seems that it is not making the absolute best possible advantage of the index (that is, starting to group items as items are loaded, rather than loading them all in memory first). But it is still certainly worth doing.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation. `$group` does not use an index, just like `$sort` do not use an index if it doesn't occur in the beginning of a pipeline. Your interpretation implies that any operator uses an index when it is fed data that has been retrieved by using an index. That is simply semantically wrong.

Comment: @Manuel No, my interpretation is that an operator uses an index when it is fed data that (a) has been retrieved using an index, and (b) the operator(s) before have not altered the order of that data, and (c) this operator uses a different, more optimal implementation than normal because MongoDB recognises (a) and (b).

Comment: Do you have any semantic reference from the docs for a)? To say that an operator uses an index when it is fed data that has been retrieved using an index is semantically wrong. It is not the operator that uses the index, but the operator before that. It is even contradicting the MongoDB docs that say that in an aggregate pipeline only `match` and `sort` can use an index, but according to your interpretation also the `group` operator “uses an index” when it is fed data that has been retrieved with `match` using an index. Which operator uses an index is evident clearly in `executionStats`.

Answer (score 2):

Per Mongo's 4.2 [$group documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#optimization-to-return-the-first-document-of-each-group), there is a special optimization for $first:

> **Optimization to Return the First Document of Each Group**
>
> If a pipeline sorts and groups by the same field and the $group stage only uses the $first accumulator operator, consider adding an index on the grouped field which matches the sort order. In some cases, the $group stage can use the index to quickly find the first document of each group.

It makes sense, since only the first entry in an ordered index should be needed for each bin in the $group stage.  Unfortunately, in my 3.6 testing, I haven't been able to get nearly the performance I would expect if the index were really being used.  I've posted about that problem in detail in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369835/using-an-index-with-mongos-first-group-operator).

**EDIT 2020-04-23**

I confirmed with Atlas's MongoDB Support that this $first optimization was added in Mongo 4.2, hence my trouble getting it to work with 3.6.  There is also a bug preventing it from working with a composite $group _id at the moment.  Further details are available in the post that I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, indexes can cover an aggregation pipeline. In MongoDB 2.6 and 3.0, indexes could not cover an aggregation pipeline since even when the pipeline uses an index, aggregation still requires access to the actual documents.

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes

Comment: The question was specifically about whether the `$group` stage can take advantage of the sorted-ness of an index. That link doesn't say anything about that. Even if an index covers the query, MongoDB may still needlessly re-sort the data in `$group` stage.