# MongoDB count in array very slow

Tags: mongodb

My data is as follow:

```
{
   "timestamp":1467349392   ,
   "alert_tag":[  
      "alert_source: WS2",
      "alert_severity:warning",
      "alert 
    _object:Sensor-840",
      "alert_type_id:2",
      "alert_status:resovled"
   ],
   "alert_info":{  
      "t":1
   },
   "server_created_timestamp":NumberLong("1467349309392"),
   "alert_ 
    id":"20"
}
```

I have about two million records in the collection. I am trying to count the number of unique alert_status, alert_object, alert_source that matches the query. The following is  my aggregation pipeline (match, unwind, group, sort, project, group) and it takes about 40s to complete:

```
{  
   "$match":{  
      "alert_tag":{  
         "$in":[  
            "alert_status:pending"
         ]
      }
   }
},
{  
   "$unwind":"$alert_tag"
},
{  
   "$group":{  
      "_id":"$alert_tag",
      "count":{  
         "$sum":1
      }
   }
},
{  
   "$sort":{  
      "_id":1
   }
},
{  
   "$project":{  
      "tmp":{  
         "alert":"$_id",
         "count":"$count"
      }
   }
},
{  
   "$group":{  
      "_id":null,
      "total":{  
         "$sum":1
      },
      "data":{  
         "$addToSet":"$tmp"
      }
   }
}
```

How can I improve the  performance? `alert_tag` has been indexed

Comment: How long does a simple `find().count()` query take (and why is that not sufficient)?

Comment: Because we want to show the all the available statuses during the period

Comment: So it's not just "count the number of alert_status that is pending." ? Anyway, how long does the count() take?

Comment: No, count by type, status, object, and severity. e.g. tell people what type of alerts are there

Comment: I think the two steps that could take a long time are the `unwind` and the first `group`. Can you try them separately to see if one is particularly long to execute? Btw, your `$in` is useless in the `match` stage.

Comment: The $in is not useless because I want to get the distinct count that matches. unwind itself is fast. $group is slow

Comment: `$in` is useless because [you use it with a single-value array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/): `$match":{"alert_tag":"alert_status:pending"}` is enough. However, I agree this is not the main issue :)

Comment: And unfortunately a `group` operation does not use indexes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455752/mongodb-aggregation-framework-does-group-use-index