# MongoDB aggregate group optimisation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB 3.2.1 and I'm trying to optimise my query. Which is simple, I'm grouping by `COMMAND` and getting `first object` (all fields). Now it takes around 6 seconds.

```
[
  { "$sort": { "c": 1} },
  { "$group":
    {
      "_id": "$c",
      "c" : { "$first": "$c"},
      "i" : { "$first": "$i"},
      "t" : { "$first": "$t"},
      "v" : { "$first": "$v"}
    }
  }
]
```

I've added indexes:

```
c:-1
t:-1
c:-1,t:-1
```

Do you have any ideas how to optimise it more? I noticed that if I don't return `v` param (where I have a data fields) then time is around 2.5s

DB returns 33 documents from 1957461. One of the commands have the most entries c:188 = 1709151

**Update**

I removed `sort` and now is faster takes 4.5s, without `v` param 2s

```
[
  { "$group":
    {
      "_id": "$c",
      "c" : { "$first": "$c"},
      "i" : { "$first": "$i"},
      "t" : { "$first": "$t"},
      "v" : { "$first": "$v"}
    }
  }
]
```

When I get only `i` param it takes around 1.5s

```
[
  { "$group":
    {
      "_id": "$c",
      "i" : { "$first": "$i"}
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Groups doesn't use index data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455752/mongodb-aggregation-framework-does-group-use-index Just for info

Comment: You can remove sort, e.g. anyway get results by groups, only sort take much time.

Comment: index is working in sort bt not in group