# Mongo aggregation query not using indexes

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a collection of orders.

```
{
  orderId: 23322,
  clientId: 1111
  otherFields: "sda"
}
```

There's an index on `{clientId:1}`

The query I'm running is

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:"$clientId", count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$match:{count:{$gt:250}}}
])
```

Why is this using COLLSCAN. Why not just the INDEX? I'd imagine, perhaps erroneously, that an index is kind of like a Map where clientId is the key, and a list of orders is the value. Why can't this query just use the index?

Is there a way to run this query against the index alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, only the `$match` and `$sort` operators can take advantage of indexes when placed at the beginning of the aggregation pipeline. You can [read more about it here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance).

Also, check this closely related question:
[Mongodb Aggregation Framework: Does $group use index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455752/mongodb-aggregation-framework-does-group-use-index)