# Mongodb aggregate $group stage takes a long time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-performance

I'm practicing how to use **MongoDB aggregation**, but they seem to take a really long time (running time).

The **problem** seems to happen whenever I use `$group`. All other queries run just fine.

I have some **`1.3` million dummy documents** that need to perform **two basic operations**: get a **count** of the IP addresses and **unique** IP addresses.

My **schema** looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id":"5da51af103eb566faee6b8b4",
    "ip_address":"...",
    "country":"CL",
    "browser":{
        "user_agent":...",
    }
}
```

Running a basic `$group` query takes about `12`s on average, which is much too slow.

I did a little research, and someone suggested creating an **index** on `ip_addresses`. That seems to have slowed it down because queries now take `13-15`s.

I use MongoDB and the **query** I'm running looks like this:

```js
    visitorsModel.aggregate([
        {
            '$group': {
                '_id': '$ip_address',
                'count': {
                    '$sum': 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]).allowDiskUse(true)
        .exec(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) throw err;

            return res.send({
                uniqueCount: docs.length
            })
        })
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention, someone suggested it might be a hardware issue? I'm running the query on a core i5, 8GB RAM laptop if it helps.

**Edit 2**: The query plan:

```
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                },
                "fields" : {
                    "ip_address" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "metrics.visitors",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {

                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                },
                "executionStats" : {
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "nReturned" : 1387324,
                    "executionTimeMillis" : 7671,
                    "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                    "totalDocsExamined" : 1387324,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 1387324,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 9,
                        "works" : 1387326,
                        "advanced" : 1387324,
                        "needTime" : 1,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 10930,
                        "restoreState" : 10930,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "docsExamined" : 1387324
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$ip_address",
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: did you look at the query execution stats ? Please share them

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar Added it to the original question

Comment: The query plan shows a COLLSCAN, and the query performance can benefit from an index. Are there any indexes defined on the collection?

Comment: Can you tell why you are using the `allowDiskUse` and the `exec` ?

Comment: Also see these: (1) [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), (2) [db.collection.aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html), _and_ [$group (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Comment: If you are learning or practicing aggregation queries, try them from **mongo shell** command line tool; it is easy to work with initially (than from NodeJS). Once, you get the query right, you can implement it in Node.

Comment: @prasad_ Yeah. I've added an index on `ip_address`. I've tried both exec and the other method, but haven't seen any difference between the two. I'm using `alliwDiskUse` because without it, mongodb goes above the 16mb limit and the query fails. Is it not supposed to be used with `exec`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the docs are where I got the `$group` example to begin with...

Comment: Running `db.collection.getIndexes` returns  `[
...
{
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "ip_address" : 1
  },
  "name" : "ip_address_1",
  "ns" : "metrics.visitors",
  "background" : true
 },
...
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some info about using `$group` aggregation stage, if it uses indexes, and its limitations and what can be tried to overcome these.

**1. The $group Stage Doesn't Use Index**:
[Mongodb Aggregation: Does $group use index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455752/mongodb-aggregation-framework-does-group-use-index)

**2. $group Operator and Memory**:

> The `$group` stage has a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. By default, if
>   the stage exceeds this limit, `$group` returns an error. To allow for
>   the handling of large datasets, set the `allowDiskUse` option to true.
>   This flag enables $group operations to write to temporary files.

See [MongoDb docs on $group Operator and Memory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-memory-limit)

**3. An Example Using $group and Count**:

A collection called as `cities`:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "city" : "Bangalore", "country" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 2, "city" : "New York", "country" : "United States" }
{ "_id" : 3, "city" : "Canberra", "country" : "Australia" }
{ "_id" : 4, "city" : "Hyderabad", "country" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 5, "city" : "Chicago", "country" : "United States" }
{ "_id" : 6, "city" : "Amritsar", "country" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 7, "city" : "Ankara", "country" : "Turkey" }
{ "_id" : 8, "city" : "Sydney", "country" : "Australia" }
{ "_id" : 9, "city" : "Srinagar", "country" : "India" }
{ "_id" : 10, "city" : "San Francisco", "country" : "United States" }
```

**Query** the collection to count the cities by each country:

```
db.cities.aggregate( [
    { $group: { _id: "$country", cityCount: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $project: { country: "$_id", _id: 0, cityCount: 1 } }
] )
```

The **Result**:

```
{ "cityCount" : 3, "country" : "United States" }
{ "cityCount" : 1, "country" : "Turkey" }
{ "cityCount" : 2, "country" : "Australia" }
{ "cityCount" : 4, "country" : "India" }
```

**4. Using allowDiskUse Option**:

```
db.cities.aggregate( [
    { $group: { _id: "$country", cityCount: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $project: { country: "$_id", _id: 0, cityCount: 1 } }
],  { allowDiskUse : true } )
```

Note, in this case it makes no difference in query performance or output. This is to show the usage only.

**5. Some Options to Try (suggestions)**:

You can try a few things to get some result (for trial purposes only):

- Use `$limit` stage and restrict the number of documents processed and
  see what is the result. For example, you can try `{ $limit: 1000 }`.
  Note this stage needs to come before the `$group` stage.
- You can also use the `$match`, `$project` stages before the `$group`
  stage to    control the *shape* and *size* of the input. This may
  return a result    (instead of an error).

---

**[EDIT ADD]**

**Notes on Distinct and Count:**

Using the same `cities` collection - to get unique countries and a count of them you can try using the aggregate stage `$count` along with `$group` as in the following two queries.

**Distinct:**

```
db.cities.aggregate( [
   { $match: { country: { $exists: true } } },
   { $group: { _id: "$country" } },
   { $project: { country: "$_id", _id: 0 } }
] )
```

The Result:

```
{ "country" : "United States" }
{ "country" : "Turkey" }
{ "country" : "India" }
{ "country" : "Australia" }
```

To get the above result as a single document with an array of unique values, use the `$addToSet`operator:

```
db.cities.aggregate( [
   { $match: { country: { $exists: true } } },
   { $group: { _id: null, uniqueCountries: { $addToSet:  "$country" } } },
   { $project: { _id: 0 } },
] )
```

The Result: `{ "uniqueCountries" : [ "United States", "Turkey", "India", "Australia" ] }`

**Count:**

```
db.cities.aggregate( [
   { $match: { country: { $exists: true } } },
   { $group: { _id: "$country" } },
   { $project: { country: "$_id", _id: 0 } },
   { $count: "uniqueCountryCount" }
] )
```

The Result: `{ "uniqueCountryCount" : 4 }`

In the above queries the `$match` stage is used to filter any documents with non-existing or null `country`field. The `$project` stage reshapes the result document(s).

**MongoDB Query Language:**

Note the two queries get similar results when using the *MongoDB query language* commands: `db.collection.distinct("country")` and `db.cities.distinct("country").length` (note the `distinct` returns an array).

Answer (score 0):

You can create index

```
db.collectionname.createIndex( { ip_address: "text" } )
```

Try this, it is more faster.
I think it will help you.

Comment: The collection already has an index. Running this returns `{..."note" : "all indexes already exist"`...}

Comment: What is the datatype of ip_address, you have taken?