# How to do a distinct count in mongodb that uses a compound index that extends more than 16mb

Tags: mongodb

I have a table that is called "sessions"

In the table I've two fields that are a compound index:

- app (ObjectId)
- udid (string)

I would like to count the amount of distinct udids in a specific app.

The first way that I went was:

```
db.getCollection('sessions').distinct('udid', {"app" : ObjectId("...")}).length
```

My problem is that the result is bigger than 16mb and I get the following errors "distinct too big, 16mb cap"

Then I tried to go with the next solution:

```
db.getCollection('sessions').aggregate([
    {$match: {app: ObjectId('...')}},
    {$group:{_id: '$udid'}},
    {$count: 'id'}
])
```

The problem is that it isn't using the compound index it is first finding all the $match and only after it, it is doing the group therefore it isn't using for the group the index. 
This makes that this query is very slow on a 3 million document schema it takes 50 sec.

It would be great if someone could tell me another way to do a distinct count.

Comment: Can you share the query plan for the aggregation?

Comment: @prasad_ I've put all the information in the question. The plan that was selected is: "stage": "IXSCAN" with  keyPattern: { "app" : 1, "time" : 1}, and not keyPattern { "app" : 1, "udid" : 1}. This is because it is first doing the match on app alone therefor the index app_1_time_1 is good for it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `app_1_time_1` index?

Comment: @prasad_ I've another field that is time, and I've on it also a compound index. Due to the fact that the search is only on app it can take any index that starts with app.

Comment: See these: [Mongodb Aggregation Framework: Does $group use index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455752/mongodb-aggregation-framework-does-group-use-index) _and_ [Aggregation Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes).

Comment: @prasad_ so what you're telling there is no more efficient way to do it.